# How to declare a generic class using a generic interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I am having difficulties understanding how to declare generics, and declare methods handling generics in C#.

For example :

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Value();
}
// error
public interface IFooBuilder<F> where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    F BuildFoo();
}


public class FooA : IFoo<int>
{
    public int Value()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
// error
public class FooBuilderA : IFooBuilder<FooA>
{
    public FooA BuildFoo()
    {
        return new FooA();
    }
}

public class FooBuilders
{
    // error
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, IFooBuilder<IFoo<T>>> builders = new();

    // error
    public static void Register(string name, IFooBuilder<F> builder) where F : IFoo<T>, T
    {
        builders.Add(name, builder);
    }
    // error
    public static B Get<B>(string name) where B : IFooBuilder<F>, F : IFoo<T>, T
    {
        return (B)builders[name];
    } 
}
```

I understand simple uses, like the interface `IFoo<T>` and it's implementing class `FooA`, but I'm puzzled with `IFooBuilder` and `FooBuilders`; how do I use generics who also use generics?

(Error handling is not an issue, I just want to understand how this code could compile.)

How would `FooBuilderRegistry` be declared in order to register and return the correct types?

### ** Update **

Thanks to Kit's answer, I refactored the code, and got to this point :

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Value();
}
public interface IFooBuilder<F,T> where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    F BuildFoo();
}


public class FooA : IFoo<int>
{
    public int Value() { return 0; }
}
public class FooBuilderA : IFooBuilder<FooA>
{
    public FooA BuildFoo()
    {
        return new FooA();
    }
}

public class FooBuilders
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic> builders = new();

    public static void Register<F,T>(string name, IFooBuilder<F, T> builder) where F : IFoo<T>, T
    {
        builders.Add(name, builder);
    }

    // ERROR                                          IFoo is in error, here vv
    public static B Get<B,F,T>(string name) where B : IFooBuilder<F, T>, F : IFoo<T>, T
    {
        return (B)builders[name];
    }
}
```

I do not understand why `F : IFoo<T>` would be an error.

Comment: `public interface IFooBuilder<F> where F : IFoo<T>, T` makes no obvious sense. `public interface IFooBuilder<F, T> where F : IFoo<T>` does, to some extent, but since you don't want to be hoisting around `T` just for a builder `IFooBuilder<T> { public IFoo<T> BuildFoo(); }` makes more sense. For one-method builders in particular I wouldn't even use *that* and just use `Func<IFoo<T>>`; delegates are more flexible than requiring the user to declare a class with an interface. For `FooBuilders`, you'll have to go dynamic and use runtime casting, since there's nothing unifying different `IFoo<T>`s.

Comment: When it comes to generics, unless you can explain to a rubber duck, you're probably overengineering. You should edit your question and explain what you need in simple terms.

Comment: `public static B Get<B,F,T>(string name)  where B : IFooBuilder<F, T> where F : IFoo<T>, T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is because you did not add `T` as a type parameter to `IFooBuilder<F>`. You are varying by two type arguments, `F` and `T`, so it should be `IFooBuilder<F, T>`.

That means your class `FooBuilderA` should derive from `IFooBuilder<FooA, int>` or perhaps `IFooBuilder<IFoo<int>, int>`.

That will get you past the first two errors, but it looks like `FooBuilders` will need to be altered quite a bit because your dictionary won't be able to hold heterogenous values. You might need something like a dictionary of `dynamic`:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic> builders = new();
```

Your methods in `FooBuilders` will have to be modified to take the generic arguments. These

```
// error
public static void Register(string name, IFooBuilder<F> builder) where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    builders.Add(name, builder);
}
// error
public static B Get<B,F,T>(string name) where B : IFooBuilder<F, T> where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    return (B)builders[name];
}
```

plainly cannot compile. Their signatures should look like

```
public static void Register(string name, IFooBuilder<F, T> builder) where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    builders.Add(name, builder);
}

public static B Get<B, F, T>(string name) where B : IFooBuilder<F, T> where F : IFoo<T>, T
{
    return (B)builders[name];
}
```

Essentially the errors are three-fold

- at compile time, you have not specified all the generic arguments
- at runtime you will need to invoke a builder, which means you need the correct type arguments
- if you want a dictionary of heterogenous (by type) builders, you can use dynamic as a way to store them and call them, but with appropriate casts.

I may have missed something not being in front of a compiler or unit tests, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me narrow the problem down, I have updated the question because there is one last bit of problem that I do not understand.

Comment: See my update. It was a simple syntax error on my part. A comma should have been a `where`. What happens when you're not sitting in your IDE :)

Comment: Why `dynamic`, not just `object`?

Comment: @GuruStron Maybe not this case, but I was thinking back to cases where you invoke a handler that has similar signatures in terms of number of arguments and return value. e.g. a `Handler<T,U>` class with `T Handle<T, U>(U arg)`. These handlers could all be in the same <string, dynamic> dictionary: `Handler<int, string>`, `Handler<string, bool>`, etc. Provided the actual arguments were correct you could simply call `handler.Handle(value)` because handler is dynamic. It's not typesafe, but well encapsulated code this is a great way to avoid loads of reflection.

Comment: @Kit thanks! I remember, now, why I hated generics in C#. The way Java handled it seemed much more intuitive to me. Both of these languages are quite far back, today.

Comment: You must be used to Haskell or something. There's more room for C# to grow for sure.